# Calculate the percentile rank of a set of scores based on a population

Tags: r, vectorization, ranking, percentile

I have a set of scores on 31 competencies for one individual

```
data <- data.frame(scores=sample(100,31,replace=T),row.names=paste0("X",1:31))
```

and I have a benchmark file for scores of 100 (or any number) individuals on the same 31 competencies

```
bmark <- data.frame(replicate(31,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))
```

I need to calculate the percentile rank of each competency score for the individual relative to the benchmark for that competency, the output should look something like this (random values, just to demonstrate the required format)

```
data <- data.frame(scores=sample(100,31,replace=T),percentile=sample(100,31,replace=T),row.names=paste0("X",1:31))
```

I can calculate each score's percentile rank using a basic percentile formula:

```
length(bmark$X31[bmark$X31<data$scores[rownames(data)=="X31"]])/length(bmark$X31)*100
```

But I don't know how to make this work across the whole data set at once, so that each row in `data$percentile` has the appropriate value for the corresponding competency in the benchmark file. I could do this with a loop, but still not great with R vectorisation.

EDIT:
Here is a dput of my data frames for subsequent comments/questions below. Note that this is a snippet of the bmark data (only a few columns/'competencies'). Data is in long format (thus has all compentencies) and has a column identifier for subject (data$Split).
bmark

```
    bmark <- structure(list(FinPerf = c(2.41333333333333, 2.94047619047619, 
2.87538940809969, 2.16666666666667, 2.34146341463415, 2.425, 
2.58148148148148, 2.97297297297297, 2.325, 2.52542372881356, 
2.35593220338983, 1.69105691056911, 2.73493975903614, 2.01666666666667, 
1.94010416666667, 1.94603174603175, 2.56666666666667, 2.48550724637681, 
2.61846110878369, 2.15873015873016, 2.56565656565657, 2.23529411764706, 
2.98974358974359, 3.09195402298851, 2.59289617486339, 2.44306418219462, 
2.72345679012346, 2.85714285714286, 2.62962962962963, 2.90833333333333
), Opt = c(2.74, 2.83928571428571, 2.87383177570093, 2.56692506459948, 
2.64634146341463, 2.6625, 2.53333333333333, 3.31081081081081, 
2.4, 2.50847457627119, 2.55932203389831, 1.89024390243902, 2.60240963855422, 
2.3, 2.3203125, 2.24761904761905, 2.85, 2.76086956521739, 2.78064516129032, 
2.30952380952381, 2.65151515151515, 2.29411764705882, 3.06923076923077, 
3.12931034482759, 2.64754098360656, 2.08695652173913, 2.41111111111111, 
2.78571428571429, 2.88888888888889, 2.9625), SatExp = c(2.44, 
2.58928571428571, 2.70093457943925, 2.11111111111111, 2.29268292682927, 
2.525, 2.33888888888889, 3.10810810810811, 2.375, 2.73728813559322, 
2.6864406779661, 1.91463414634146, 2.65060240963855, 2.225, 2.01171875, 
1.94285714285714, 2.6, 2.51086956521739, 2.83225806451613, 2.28571428571429, 
2.84848484848485, 2.02941176470588, 3.13076923076923, 3.22413793103448, 
2.45491803278689, 2.5, 2.78518518518518, 2.85714285714286, 2.75925925925926, 
2.975)), .Names = c("FinPerf", "Opt", "SatExp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

And data

```
    data <- structure(list(Area.short = structure(c(13L, 25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 
16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 
27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 
25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 
8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 
15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 
21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 
19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 
16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 
27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 
25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 
8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 
15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 
21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 
19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 
16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 
27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 29L, 17L, 13L, 
25L, 28L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 20L, 21L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 26L, 
8L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 27L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 10L, 
15L, 29L, 17L), .Label = c("ACHIEVEMENT", "Apprec", "Bal", "Belong", 
"BrandPass", "Burn", "Care", "Comms", "Comp", "CONNECTION", "Consul", 
"Fam", "FinPerf", "Forw", "FRANCHISE PARTNERSHIP", "Ful", "GENSAT", 
"Harm", "Innov", "Integ", "LeadCom", "LEADERSHIP", "LIFESTYLE", 
"MarkSup", "Opt", "Part", "PracSup", "SatExp", "SUPPORT", "Syst", 
"Train"), class = "factor"), MM = c(22.8758169934641, 29.4117647058824, 
7.84313725490196, -29.4117647058824, 11.7647058823529, -3.26797385620914, 
7.84313725490196, 11.1111111111111, 15.6862745098039, 9.80392156862744, 
9.80392156862744, 5.88235294117648, 33.3333333333333, 17.6470588235294, 
13.7254901960784, 19.6078431372549, 11.7647058823529, 1.96078431372548, 
13.7254901960784, 21.5686274509804, 15.6862745098039, 11.1111111111111, 
21.5686274509804, 1.96078431372548, 20.4481792717087, -3.26797385620914, 
10.1307189542484, 20.0980392156863, 10.9803921568627, 14.7058823529412, 
11.7647058823529, 22.2222222222222, 16.6666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 
-25, 0, -11.1111111111111, 0, -5.55555555555557, 16.6666666666667, 
58.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667, 0, 25, 11.1111111111111, 
0, 33.3333333333333, 8.33333333333333, -11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 
50, 0, 11.1111111111111, 16.6666666666667, 25, 16.6666666666667, 
-9.25925925925926, 13.8888888888889, 10.4166666666667, 8.33333333333333, 
19.4444444444444, 10.3448275862069, 100, 66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 
-33.3333333333333, 100, 55.5555555555556, 100, 55.5555555555556, 
100, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, -11.1111111111111, 100, 
77.7777777777778, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 
11.1111111111111, 77.7777777777778, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
33.3333333333333, 100, 33.3333333333333, 80.952380952381, 55.5555555555556, 
44.4444444444444, 66.6666666666667, 53.3333333333333, 55.5555555555556, 
57.4712643678161, 7.40740740740741, 33.3333333333333, -5.55555555555557, 
-5.55555555555557, -5.55555555555557, -14.8148148148148, -22.2222222222222, 
-3.70370370370369, -22.2222222222222, -27.7777777777778, -16.6666666666667, 
7.40740740740741, 22.2222222222222, 7.40740740740741, 3.70370370370369, 
5.55555555555557, 5.55555555555557, 14.8148148148148, -3.70370370370369, 
5.55555555555557, 11.1111111111111, 0, 18.5185185185185, -11.1111111111111, 
11.1111111111111, -12.3456790123457, -10.1851851851852, 9.72222222222223, 
5.55555555555557, 5.55555555555557, 0.766283524904221, 25.9259259259259, 
27.7777777777778, 11.1111111111111, -55.5555555555556, 22.2222222222222, 
3.70370370370369, 27.7777777777778, 29.6296296296296, 38.8888888888889, 
11.1111111111111, 22.2222222222222, 11.1111111111111, 38.8888888888889, 
22.2222222222222, 29.6296296296296, 16.6666666666667, 11.1111111111111, 
-3.70370370370369, 22.2222222222222, 11.1111111111111, 27.7777777777778, 
18.5185185185185, 14.8148148148148, -5.55555555555557, 22.2222222222222, 
0, 22.2222222222222, 29.1666666666667, 11.1111111111111, 13.8888888888889, 
16.0919540229885, -6.17283950617284, 11.1111111111111, -18.5185185185185, 
14.8148148148148, -18.5185185185185, -28.3950617283951, -44.4444444444444, 
-16.0493827160494, -29.6296296296296, -25.9259259259259, -33.3333333333333, 
3.70370370370369, -3.70370370370369, -18.5185185185185, -18.5185185185185, 
-7.40740740740741, -14.8148148148148, -6.17283950617284, -28.3950617283951, 
3.70370370370369, -3.70370370370369, -16.0493827160494, -11.1111111111111, 
-7.40740740740741, -4.76190476190478, -20.1646090534979, -17.9012345679012, 
-14.8148148148148, -14.8148148148148, -8.02469135802468, -13.6653895274585, 
42.2222222222222, 53.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, -86.6666666666667, 
26.6666666666667, 2.22222222222221, 46.6666666666667, 20, 60, 
46.6666666666667, 53.3333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 
51.1111111111111, 42.2222222222222, 46.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
11.1111111111111, 55.5555555555556, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
33.3333333333333, 55.5555555555556, 13.3333333333333, 42.8571428571429, 
-2.22222222222221, 33.3333333333333, 51.6666666666667, 36, 35.5555555555555, 
32.4137931034483, 77.7777777777778, 44.4444444444444, 44.4444444444444, 
-66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 62.962962962963, 100, 77.7777777777778, 
77.7777777777778, 55.5555555555556, 66.6666666666667, 11.1111111111111, 
88.8888888888889, 70.3703703703704, 62.962962962963, 55.5555555555556, 
55.5555555555556, 11.1111111111111, 70.3703703703704, 55.5555555555556, 
44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 62.962962962963, 11.1111111111111, 
58.7301587301587, 45.679012345679, 55.5555555555556, 72.2222222222222, 
46.6666666666667, 48.1481481481482, 53.639846743295), Split = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Success4u", "NSW/ACT", 
"QLD", "SA/WA", "VIC/TAS", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Franchise Sector Benchmark"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Area.short", "MM", "Split"
), row.names = c(NA, 248L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to get the percentile on each benchmark for one subject. We use the empirical cumulative distribution function to calculate percentiles:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(595)
dat <- data.frame(scores=sample(100,31,replace=T),row.names=paste0("X",1:31))
bmark <- data.frame(replicate(31,sample(100,100,rep=TRUE)))

# Get percentile on each benchmark for one subject
dat$percentile = mapply(function(ref, subj) {
  ecdf(ref)(subj)*100
}, ref=bmark, subj=dat$scores)

dat
```

> ```
>     scores percentile
> X1      28         25
> X2      25         30
> X3      91         92
> ...
> X29     42         46
> X30     76         71
> X31      1          2
> ```

Here's a boxplot of the distribution of `bmark` for each competency, along with a red dot showing where the subject scored on each of them:

```
boxplot(bmark)
points(1:31, data$scores, pch=16, col="red")
```

[image]

If you have multiple subjects, you can get their percentiles all at once. We take the `mapply` code from above, which calculates percentiles for a single subject, and wrap it in `sapply`, which feeds the `mapply` code each subject in succession and returns all of the results in a single matrix:

```
# Scores on 31 benchmarks for 20 subjects. Each column is a subject.
set.seed(58)
subjects = as.data.frame(replicate(20, sample(100, 31, replace=TRUE)))

# Get percentile on each benchmark for each subject
percentile.score = sapply(subjects, function(s) {
  mapply(function(ref, subj) {
    ecdf(ref)(subj)*100
  }, ref=bmark, subj=s)
})

percentile.score
```

> ```
>     V1 V2 V3  V4 V5  V6 V7  V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
> X1  28 95  2  24 95  18 61   6 44  11  82  50  28  37  59  41  91  51  35  76
> X2  20 49 62   3 24  24 54  23 50  50  60  95  25  63  57  78  72  89  79  66
> X3  69 37 40  49 59  30 91   5 92  43  56  22  34  33  28  54  35   1  59  29
> ...
> X29 34 42 10  76 40  48 13  36 76  13  88  91  99  31  13  76  93  42  31  91
> X30 16 66 86  56 21  67 86  45 81  16  70  66  24  11  23  18  32  53  31  32
> X31 81 81 52   2  3  32 64  36 33  39  92 100  80   2  44  63  59   2  34  99
> ```

Comment: Hi @eipe10, thank you very much for your considered response, and yes, that was supposed to be `0:100`, not `0:1`! I am not really familiar with `mapply`, but I assume it is operating assuming that `dat` and `bmark` are in the same order? Is it possible for me to do that via indexing/matching column names of `bmark` and `rownames` of `dat`? In my real data set, `dat` is just part of a long data set, and I pull in chunks of data according to values in another column.

Comment: to clarify, I have a column that is the data, a column that is the competency_id, and a column that is subject_id. I'd like to use the competency_id to safely perform your operation (in the event the order changes in one or both bmark and dat). Additionally, in line with your second suggestion, I'd need to pull in subjects by their ID as my `dat` is in long format

Comment: If will be easier to answer if you provide samples of your real data. Just provide data for maybe 3 subjects and 3 competencies from the subject data, and maybe 20 scores for each of the 3 competencies from the benchmark data. Paste into your question the output of `dput(benchmark_sample)` and `dput(subject_sample)`

Comment: Hi and thanks again @eipi10 I have included a dput in the original question. To reiterate, I am trying to get the percentile of each row (corresponding to each competency) of `data$MM`, for the respective competency (column) of `bmark`. I will eventually need to do this for each 'subject' in data (`data$Split`)